# Can I use cflocation and/or cfhttp to mimic a javascript redirect with form post?

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, cflocation

I have a project that is requiring me to Post login data to another domain. After the form submission a cookie is set in the browser and the user is redirected.

I've been able to accomplish this with javascript as follows:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="headOUT">
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function redirectPost(url, data) {
               var form = document.createElement('form');
               document.body.appendChild(form);
               form.method = 'post';
               form.action = url;
               for (var name in data) {
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = 'hidden';
                    input.name = name;
                    input.value = data[name];
                    form.appendChild(input);
               }
               form.submit();
          }
     </script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#headOUT#">

<cfset htmlOUT = ''>
<cfset htmlOUT = htmlOUT & '<script type="text/javascript">'>
<cfset htmlOUT = htmlOUT & "redirectPost('#remote_url#', { authen_token: '#encryptedString#' });">
<cfset htmlOUT = htmlOUT & '</script>'>
<cfoutput>#htmlOUT#</cfoutput>
```

If I use cfhttp:

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="#remote_url#" RESOLVEURL="Yes">
     <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="authen_token" value="#encryptedString#">
</cfhttp>
```

The response does not include a cookie it is only the HTML with the meta redirect as if I logged-in from their page. But with no cookie I'm not authenticated.

Is there a way to do a redirect and a post with cfhttp and/or cflocation or is the javascript the best solution?

Comment: This should have had Coldfusion as a tag. It would have gotten more attention.

Comment: I thought the blue box that says coldfusion was a tag. Is there somewhere else I should tag posts?